# Use an assembly in an aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, .net-assembly

I have a very simple aspx script:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="MimeKit.dll" %>
<%
Response.Write("test");
%>
```

The MimeKit.dll is in the same folder as this script.

I find answers that tell me to put it in the bin folder.  I don't have a bin folder, this is just a single file - not created in Visual Studio and not part of a project or app.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do, that does not involve using Visual studio, to be able to use this dll.

I get error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MimeKit.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I run the script like so:

```
http://localhost/test/mail.aspx
```

I have created a bin folder at http://localhost/bin and put the dll in there.  I have also created a bin folder at http://localhost/test/bin.  I get the same error.

Have also tried:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\gacutil.exe" /i MimeKit.dll
```

which said it was successful, but still I get the same error.

Also did the gacutil using the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 - made no difference.

Also added the following to web.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly" publicKeyToken="bede1c8a46c66814" culture="neutral" />
            <codeBase version="2.1.0.0" href="http://localhost/bin/MimeKit.dll"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Still no go - same error message.  (Note: I got the public key token by using `gacutil /l MimeKit`.

Discovered that MimeKit has a dependency (BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll), so tried just using that:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll" %>
<%
Response.Write("test");
%>
```

Same error and this has no dependencies.

Pulling my hair out - does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I was barking up the wrong tree. This is what I needed.  Didn't need to register the dll, just needed to put it in the folder: http://localhost/bin

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MimeKit" %>
```